# HTML / CSS: list button among themselves

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

```
<ul class='list'>
<li class='list-item'>
    <span>Entry 1</span>
    <span class='button-group'>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </span>
</li>
<li class='list-item'>
    <span>Entry 2</span>
    <span class='button-group'>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to position the buttons among themselves.

This doesnt work:

```
button {
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, it is just lacking some more adjustments.

Buttons, images and other similar elements tend to bleed out of their containing list items, if they are floated.

First, I recommend to float your button container instead of the button. If you need to add more buttons, they will float immediately and will be kept in the correct order.

Second, Add a height to your list items so they are at least as high as your buttons. This way, the buttons will align correctly.

```css
li {
  min-height: 24px;
}

.button-group {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
<li class='list-item'>
    <span>Entry 1</span>
    <span class='button-group'>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </span>
</li>
<li class='list-item'>
    <span>Entry 2</span>
    <span class='button-group'>
        <button>Delete</button>
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The buttons align differently and not exactly among themselves.

Comment: please show us what you want to achieve (draw it if you have to)